# How do I make my string split case insensitive?

Tags: r

Below is a piece of code that splits a large piece of text called "lines" into multiples strings. It splits whenever it detects an ending punctuation (such as . or ?) but it excludes all periods that immediately follow an abbreviation such as Mr.

```
lines<-unlist(strsplit(lines, paste("(?<=(?<!", abbr,")[\\.\\?\\!])[\\s”’]"), perl = T))
```

All of the abbreviations are stored in a vector called "abbr" and they are all capitalized (Mr., Mrs. as opposed to mr., mrs.). The problem I have with my code is that I want it to be case insensitive and detect abbreviations in the text that aren't capitalized and I want to accomplish this without simply adding lower case versions of each abbreviation to the abbr vector.

Comment: Can. you show a small reproducible example Inside the square bracket, you ddon't need to escape

Comment: My answer below is likely incomplete. As akrun suggested, it would be incredibly helpful to improve the question with sample data. While I might be reading into your question, this sample data should be clear where you expect it to "detect abbreviations" and where you expect it to *not* detect them.

Comment: compare: `strsplit('aAaaA', 'a')` to `strsplit('aAaaA', '(?i)a')`

Answer (score 1):

`strsplit` itself does not offer case insensitivity, but you can make an equivalent (if not regex-inefficient) with

```r
abbr <- "SomeText"
abbr1 <- strsplit(abbr, "")
abbr1
# [[1]]
# [1] "S" "o" "m" "e" "T" "e" "x" "t"
abbr2 <- paste(sprintf("[%s%s]", toupper(abbr1[[1]]), tolower(abbr1[[1]])), collapse = "")
abbr2
# [1] "[Ss][Oo][Mm][Ee][Tt][Ee][Xx][Tt]"
```

and use `abbr2` in place of `abbr` in your code above.

Comment: This is the output of my abbr file before using your code:                                                                                                        [1] "Mr"   "Mrs"  "Ms"   "Dr"   "Ave"  "Blvd" "Rd"   "Mt"   "Capt" "Maj"  "Co"   "Sr"   "St"   "II"   "III" 
[16] "IV"   "V"    "VI"   "VII"  "VIII" "IX"   "X"    "XI"   "XII"  "hs"

Comment: and after using your code abbr2 becomes the following:  
[1] "[Mm][Rr]"

Comment: also I have this line of code in my original code in order to make the strsplit work:   
abbr<-paste(abbr, collapse="|")

Comment: I don't know, Davraham. Please consider [edit]ing your question and adding representative sample data and your expected output.